# How to create an JNI Android Studio Project with multiple static libs

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I'm converting our game from using ndk-build to using Android Studio and CMake.

The app is a JNI app taking the following form:

---

A Java main activity (single, very basic .java file)

c++ app code (game code)

c++ physics code  (to be compiled and linked as a static lib)

c++ graphics code (to be compiled and linked as a static lib)

---

These 3 files are compiled into a shared .so lib to be loaded and run by the main activity.

How does this translate into gradle build files and cmakelists?

I've seen lots of examples that just link in external static libs, that's of no use. I need to compile them too and I want them to show up in the project view to I can edit the source.

It would also be good if I could just drop the static lib 'projects' into other apps too, while retaining the ability to edit the source of these libs (similar to a visual studio project file.

Is this possible?

Many thanks,

Steve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library( physics STATIC
         physics/src1.cpp physics/src2.cpp )
add_library( graphics STATIC
         graphics/src1.cpp graphics/src2.cpp )
add_library( game SHARED
         game/src1.cpp game/src2.cpp )
target_link_libraries( game
         physics graphics
         log
)
```

Or you can split it to multiple files:

**physics/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library( physics STATIC
         src1.cpp src2.cpp )
```

**graphics/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library( graphics STATIC
         src1.cpp src2.cpp )
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_subdirectory( physics )
add_subdirectory( graphics )
add_library( game SHARED
         game/src1.cpp game/src2.cpp )
target_link_libraries( game
         physics graphics
         log
)
```